# React.addons.TestUtils.renderIntoDocument always returns null

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am learning Jest & trying to integrated unit tests into my existing ES6 React application. For some reason, `React.addons.TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` is always returning null. Can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

Many thanks.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test.jest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^5.2.0",
    "jest-cli": "^0.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.13.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react"
    ],
    "testFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json"
    ]
  }
}
```

**__tests__/foo-test.jsx**

```
/* global describe, it, expect */

'use strict'

import React from 'react/addons'

const { addons: { TestUtils } } = React

describe('Foo', () => {
  it('is a react element', () => {
    let component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <div>foo</div>
    )

    expect(TestUtils.isElement(component)).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

**Results**

```
$ npm test

> test.jest@1.0.0 test /home/markus/Desktop/test.jest
> jest

Using Jest CLI v0.4.5
 FAIL  src/__tests__/foo-test.jsx (1.287s)
● Foo › it is a react element
  - Expected false to be truthy.
        at Spec.<anonymous> (/home/markus/Desktop/test.jest/src/__tests__/foo-test.jsx:15:44)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
1 test failed, 0 tests passed (1 total)
Run time: 1.555s
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

### Update

The [ES6 example](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/examples/react-es6) is also not working. Throws a ton of warnings before failing when it tries to read from a null value. The [ES5 example](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/examples/react), however, does work. Might be an upstream babel-jest problem?

**Results**

```
$ npm test

> @ test /home/markus/Desktop/jest/examples/react-es6
> node ../../bin/jest.js

Using Jest CLI v0.4.5
 FAIL  __tests__/CheckboxWithLabel-test.js (1.697s)
Warning: getDOMNode(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Use React.findDOMNode(component) instead.
Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks.
Warning: replaceProps(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Instead, call React.render again at the top level.
Warning: replaceState(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Refactor your code to use setState instead (see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3236).
Warning: setProps(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Instead, call React.render again at the top level.
● CheckboxWithLabel › it changes the text after click
  - TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
        at Spec.<anonymous> (/home/markus/Desktop/jest/examples/react-es6/__tests__/CheckboxWithLabel-test.js:19:24)
        at jasmine.Block.execute (/home/markus/Desktop/jest/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:1065:17)
        at jasmine.Queue.next_ (/home/markus/Desktop/jest/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:2098:31)
        at null._onTimeout (/home/markus/Desktop/jest/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:2088:18)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
1 test failed, 0 tests passed (1 total)
Run time: 1.946s
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but i think it had something do do with my node.js version. Neither v0.12.4 nor iojs v2.2.1 was working. But node v0.10.38 seems to work. Here's hoping for an update :)

Comment: Jest only supports Node 0.10. They switched to io.js but I haven't tested that myself.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like "isElement" checks for a React component instance, not a rendered tree. See the example below:

```
import ReactDomTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
```

isDOMComponent:

```
const reactTree = ReactDomTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<div />);
expect(ReactDomTestUtils.isDOMComponent(reactTree)).toBe(true);
expect(ReactDomTestUtils.isElement(reactTree)).toBe(false);
```

isElement:

```
const reactElement = <div />;
expect(ReactDomTestUtils.isDOMComponent(reactElement)).toBe(false);
expect(ReactDomTestUtils.isElement(reactElement)).toBe(true);
```